For my custom extension how can I set a badge number in the activate method if I only have one webview?
I've been scouring docs and I can't find an answer to this:   I have a custom extension with a webview.  The webview only gets initialized when the activity bar icon is clicked.  So when my activate method is called I seemingly have no way to set the badge number.  The docs I see tell me to create a treeview but I'm not using a treeview at all, just the webview that implements resolveWebviewView. So in the activate method how can I set a number that appears on the icon of my extension in the activity bar?

How is your activationEvents defined?
